# How do I initialize an Optional<List<T>>?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

It's fairly simple. I have a field for a list that may or may not be present (but that must be different from `null` as non-initialized), but while I can do

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
```

I cannot do

```
Optional<List<String>> mylist = Optional.of(new ArrayList<String>());
```

because the types don't match. This is unfortunate. I would not like to hard-wire my code to use ArrayList.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `Optional<List<String>> mylist = Optional.of(new ArrayList<String>());` compiles fine for me. There's no reason why the types shouldn't match. Also if it doesn't compile for you, include the error message you get with the javac version.

Comment: which java version and ide are you using?

Comment: @Eran, sorry, yeah, I saw that, but that was not the problem. I just typed it in wrong here in SO

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8.0.65 and I'm getting ``error: incompatible types: Optional<ArrayList<String>> cannot be converted to Optional<List<String>>``

Comment: @YassinHajaj No, the typo was not the problem.

Comment: @Antares42 Ok, retracted.

Comment: @flo Yes I do. I found it, the problem was a compliance setting that was for java 1.7

Comment: As a side note, it's rarely a good idea to put `List` into the `Optional`. Should it be different from empty list?

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes, I considered that. However, I need to differentiate between the field not being set, and the field intentionally set to null and I can't trust my users to supply an empty list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not Java, it was my Maven project setup.

I had this in my `pom.xml`

```
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

which Eclipse then dutifully imported as Java Compiler -> JDK Compliance -> 1.7, and rightfully complained.

By setting this to 1.8 my code now compiles.

Comment: Congrats on having it running! Please accept the answer (by hitting the big tick to the left of it) to show that it has resolved your problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think the error is with your syntax.

This works for me.

```
Optional<List<String>> mylist = Optional.of(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Note the change of ; to the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry, no, that was just me typing too fast. The semicolon is in the right place.

Comment: Can you paste in your #import list, could be the wrong import.

Comment: See my own answer, the problem was my project setup. JDK compliance was set to 1.7, so Eclipse was very right to complain.

Comment: Optional<List<String>> mylist = Optional.of(new ArrayList<>()); //--->It's enough